# Entering USA from Mexico with Venezuelan passport

Tags: venezuelan-citizens

My girlfriend has a Venezuelan passport, is a Mexican resident, lives and works in Mexico. She has a one way flight to the USA and 7 days later we both drive back to Mexico, where I also live and work (US Citizen). I cannot seem to find out if she needs to have a round trip ticket or if the one-way ticket will suffice.

Comment: I don't really know, but you can get a cheap bus ticket to satisfy the onward travel requirement

Comment: The most important factor in temporary admission to any country is the traveler's country of citizenship — what passport is carried. Venezuela is not a [visa-waiver country for US entry](https://travel.state.gov/content/travel/en/us-visas/tourism-visit/visa-waiver-program.html). Living in Mexico doesn't make her eligible for entry to the US. That means your girlfriend will need a US visa to fly to the US. Holding a passport from Venezuela with no US visa, the airline will prevent her boarding her Mexico > US flight, even though she has a reservation on that flight.